# Como mantener un modal abierto

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery

Compañeros me surge una inquietud, en un modal ingreso varios datos hay un campo donde me verifica si ese dato existe o no en la base al momento de darle guardar me sale una alerta y me dice que no se puede guardar y a la vez el modal se cierra.

Quiero que al momento que me salga la alerta(sweetAlert) y le de click en ok no se cierre el modal para poder cambiar solo el dato que esta mal.

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código para simularlo localmente y poder ayudarte :D

Comment: un momento ya lo comparto

Comment: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AnLwxRFwBAYpgb11Eh5ph8-HFvW39A   aquí esta el ejemplo incluyo la base de datos, al momento de ingresar hay un botón que dice ingresar y dispara un modal pidiendo nombre y apellido, en el nombre coloca Andres y en el apellido coloca Portilla, y veras la alerta. También adjunto el video del sistema principal donde requiero hacer el procedimiento. https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnLwxRFwBAYpgb1w2QOpciNsejUOjw

Comment: Por favor revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y después edita la pregunta para agregar aquí mismo el código para crear un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), así tendrás mejores oportunidades de recibir una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, si no estoy equivocado, podrías usar: [event.stopPropagation();](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)
Tal que así:

```
alert(sweetAlert);
event.stopPropagation();
```

El método stopPropagation() de la interfaz Event evita la propagación adicional del evento actual en las fases de captura y bubbling.

Espero que te pueda ayudar,
Un saludo!